# UiTableView Row Selection: How to load different controllers on tapping different UI elements in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am developing a messenger app. I have a tableview with custom cell containing an imageview and a couple of labels.

I want to load different controllers on tapping different UI elements. To be specific, I want controllerA to be loaded when imageView is tapped and controllerB when the rest of the row is selected. How can i do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UIButton` to your custom cell and connect an outlet to your `CustomCellClass`. I would recommend to create your own `CustomCellClassDelegate` protocol and to notify your ViewController when a specific button on your custom cell was tapped.